# Depth Of Field in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

This might be a "homework" issue, but I think I did enough so I can get a help here.

In my assignment, we have a working OpenGL/OpenCL application. OpenGL application renders a scene and OpenCL should apply depth-of-field like effect. OpenCL part gets texture where each pixel has original color and depth and should output color for given pixel. I'm supposed to only change per-pixel function, that is part of the OpenCL.

I already have working solution using variable-size gausian filter, that samples area around calculated pixel. But it gets laggy on higher resolutions even on my dedicated NVidia graphics card. I tried optimizing out most of the redundant operations, but I haven't gotten much performance gain.

I also tried searching the web, but all algorithms I'm finding are closely tied to graphical pipeline of OpenGL or DirectX, nothing that can be used in my scenario.

Are there any algorithms, that could work in my situation?

Comment: What kind of OpenCL application? More specifically, what does the per-pixel code do?

Comment: @delnan See edit. And I'm supposed to fill in what per-pixel code does to achieve the DoF effect.

Comment: Did you already make use of the seperability aspect of the gauss blur (so doing the 2D-Convolution as two 1D-Convolution)? If you did and it is still to slow: Do you actually need a perfect gauss-blur for your assignment, or is a somewhat lower quality blur also acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

AMD APP SDK has a sample called URNGGL (Uniform Random Noise Generator with OpenGL/OpenCL interoperability).
Have a look at https://github.com/clockfort/amd-app-sdk-fixes/tree/master/samples/opencl/cl/app/URNG.